# SoapUI : is it possible to autogenerate the value from an element in a SOAP message?

Tags: xml, random, guid, soapui

With [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) it's possible to send Soap XML message to a WCF service.
I've the following SOAP message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:my="http://myserviceprovider">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <my:ProcessOrder>
         <my:Orders>
            <my:Order>
               <my:id>randomid_1234567890</my:id>
               <my:data>ABC</my:data>
            </my:Order>
         </my:Orders>
      </my:ProcessOrder>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Because the WCF service expects a unique ID for **my:id**, I would like to know if SoapUI provides functionality to automatically generate a random GUID?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather then a random ID, I would suggest using the times stamp down to the millisecond, as the number will never be duplicated.

I haven't done this myself, but it looks like you call a string function:

```
01  ...
02  ...
03   <!-- text within dateEffectiveFrom tag is replaced with a date 10 days from today in yyyy-MM-dd format -->
04   <dateEffectiveFrom>${=  String.format('%tF', new Date() + 10) }</dateEffectiveFrom>
05   
06  <!-- TestSuite property "date" is defined as "${=  String.format('%tF', new Date() + 10) }" -->
07  <!-- Another example where dynamic date is defined as TestSuite property -->
08  <!-- and then SOAP Request can refer to this TestSuite property as shown below -->
09   <dateEffectiveFrom>${#TestSuite#date}</dateEffectiveFrom>
10  ...
11  ...
```

http://onebyteatatime.wordpress.com/2009/04/18/soapui-tips-n-tricks-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for the tip !
I used the following : <my:id>${=new Date().getTime()}</my:id>

Comment: See also this page : http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/working-with-properties.html

Answer (score 87):

This will generate a globally unique id:

```
${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have just used the below code to generate random nummber in my SOAPUI request and it worked without any problem. This will generate a random number of 10 digits.

`<val:Id UniqueID="${=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(10)}"/>`

If you want to change number of digits, just change the desired number of digits in `randomNumeric()` method.